# Regex for special characters working wrong

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create regex for checking if password got special characters.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_special_characters
It looks like this

```
new RegExp('[!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._\'",/<>?[\\\]`{|}~:;-\s]', 'g');
```

Unfortunately is also catching bare words: reg.test('word') it returns true.
Whats wrong with my regex?

Comment: Provide test-cases.

Comment: This regex is only rule for special characters

Comment: Do you want to check all special characters?

Comment: It should return true only if there is one or more of special characters in string.

Comment: reg.test('word') should return false; reg.test('word!') should return true

Comment: Because `[;-s]` matches a lot of letters. ***Double escape** backslashes in a string literal to define a *regex escape*. Better, use a **regex literal**, `/regex_pattern_here/flags_here`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative/inverse logic and test against any character that is not a number or a letter.

Using `[^A-Za-z0-9]` where caret (`^`) matches everything `except` `A-Za-z0-9`.

---

```js
const regex = /([^A-Za-z0-9]|[.\p{L}])/gm;

console.log('word: ' + regex.test('word'));
console.log('word!: ' + regex.test('word!'));
console.log('!£2word!: ' + regex.test('!£2word!'));
console.log('!ą,ć,ó!"£wordąćó: ' + regex.test('!ą,ć,ó!"£wordąćó'));
```

Comment: It's almost great , thanks a lot but how to ignore Diacritic characters like ą,ć,ó ?

Comment: @user9010407 edited.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't escape properly. RegExp object could receive a regular expression as a string but escaping matters: it needs double backslashes.

For now `[;-\s]` is equal to `[;-s]` which includes 57 characters:

```
[_;?\[\]@\\`\^<->aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsS-Z]
```

However, it should be `[;\-\\s]`.